# the first consonants of "think" and "than"

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change, old-english

think /θ/

than /ð/

As you can see,the first consonant of the two words differs.But according to the wiktionary,they are both from Proto-Germanic,and the first characters in Proto-Germanic are both þ which pronounced as θ.

So,why the pronunciation become different from each other nowadays?

the wiktionary pages: [think](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/think) and [than](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/than)